# Pandas - apply a custom function to two columns after a group_by - reformulated

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like the following:

```
    data = {'Date': ["6/28/2020",
"6/29/2020","6/30/2020","7/1/2020","7/2/2020","7/3/2020","7/4/2020","7/5/2020","7/6/2020","7/7/2020","7/8/2020","6/28/2020","6/29/2020","6/30/2020","7/1/2020","7/2/2020","7/3/2020","7/4/2020","7/5/2020","7/6/2020","7/7/2020","7/8/2020"],
            'CODE': ["ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","ABC","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF","DEF"],
            'ST_PX_CHG_PCT': [60,41,51,42,51,42,53,49,49,51,50,58,56,52,56,52,57,58,56,56,55,54],
            'BD_PX_CHG_PCT': [44,50,54,43,45,60,51,55,41,54,48,50,52,50,54,52,59,57,52,52,57,52],
            'Rota': [59,49,46,60,46,55,45,60,57,57,60,56,59,57,57,58,52,58,54,53,50,56],
            'Rolling_Beta': ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

And I have a function that calculate the  rolling beta coefficient:

```
def my_beta(X, Y, N):
    obs = len(X)
    betas = np.full(obs, np.nan)
    alphas = np.full(obs, np.nan)
    for i in range((obs - N)):
        regressor = LinearRegression()
        regressor.fit(X.to_numpy()[i: i + N + 1].reshape(-1, 1), Y.to_numpy()[i: i + N + 1])
        betas[i + N] = regressor.coef_[0]
        alphas[i + N] = regressor.intercept_
    return (alphas, betas)
```

Where N is the number of rolling days.
I would like group the data by the CODE (Knowing that i do not know how many different code I might have), and calculate the Beta by applying the `my_beta` method to the two columns: `ST_PX_CHG_PCT` and `BD_PX_CHG_PCT`.
I tried the following :

```
df.groupby(level='CODE').apply(lambda x: market_beta(x['ST_PX_CHG_PCT'], x['BD_PX_CHG_PCT'],21))
```

But it doesnt work.

It returns the following :
Out[34]:
CODE
ABC    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
DEF    ([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,...
With NO data even at the end.

Does anybody knows how to apply the my_beta formula to two columns with a 3 days roll?

Comment: In `for i in range((obs - N))`: this number is negative in your example, so the loop never runs

Comment: Ok, i just changed it to 3

Comment: Ok, my mistake. Would you know how to pull the result out  and store in dataframe with date on index and one column per CODE ? Thank you for your help @JoshFriedlander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to change your `my_beta` function to work on each group:

```
def my_beta(grp, N):
    X = grp.ST_PX_CHG_PCT
    Y = grp.BD_PX_CHG_PCT
    obs = len(X)
    betas = np.full(obs, np.nan)
    alphas = np.full(obs, np.nan)
    for i in range((obs - N)):
        regressor = LinearRegression()
        regressor.fit(X.to_numpy()[i: i + N + 1].reshape(-1, 1), Y.to_numpy()[i: i + N + 1])
        betas[i + N] = regressor.coef_[0]
        alphas[i + N] = regressor.intercept_
    grp['alphas'] = alphas
    grp['betas'] = betas
    return grp

df.groupby('CODE').apply(lambda x: my_beta(x, 3))
```